# Kotlin 2 methods with java and kotlin Function parameter (cannot access from java)

Tags: java, function, kotlin

I made a kotlin application and since there are functions in my application, I also added Java variants of my functions to make devs without kotlin std-lib able to use them. But I found that there are issues with calling these methods from java.

my kotlin implementation:

```
fun fun0(loader: java.util.function.Function<Int, String>) //method with java's Function class

fun fun0(loader: (Int) -> String) //method with kotlin's Function class
```

and how I call the method from java:

```
Function<Integer, String> param = (t) -> t.toString();
fun0(param);
```

I tried to declare the lambda explicitly (as you can see) but it didn't help.
IntelliJ doesn't show any warning or errors but when I try to compile:

[image]

Comment: It complains not about your implementation, but about Kotlin's classes. Probably you have problems with project settings. (btw I have checked for me both cases work fine)

Comment: The line number of the error is the line where I call the method (from java). I use java 8. Did you tested it in the one project? Because kotlin implementation is library for my java project so I don't have access to the source (if that matters)

Comment: My project is also based on Java 8, its build by Gradle with Kotlin plugin and `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8` library as a dependency.

Comment: since the Function1 is undefined for my project java compiler probably isn't sure which method to use. I would use java's functional interfaces in my kotlin class but I had issues with SAM conversions when called from kotlin.